# Can't run SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am new to Spring and i have to make an "HelloWorld" Application. After several attempts, i can't solve my problem.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CiaoMondoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CiaoMondoApplication.class, args);
    }

} // that's the Application

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class CiaoMondoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }

} // and that's the controller
```

Below the output, when i try to run the Application with Eclipse:

```
2019-06-11 11:09:33.089  INFO 9572 --- [           main] com.example.demo.CiaoMondoApplication    : Starting CiaoMondoApplication on Asus-Mattia with PID 9572 (C:\Users\matti\eclipse-workspace\ciao-mondo\target\classes started by matti in C:\Users\matti\eclipse-workspace\ciao-mondo)
2019-06-11 11:09:33.091  INFO 9572 --- [           main] com.example.demo.CiaoMondoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-11 11:09:33.627  INFO 9572 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-06-11 11:09:33.644  INFO 9572 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-06-11 11:09:33.895  INFO 9572 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb774f16] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-11 11:09:34.107  INFO 9572 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-11 11:09:34.127  INFO 9572 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-11 11:09:34.127  INFO 9572 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2019-06-11 11:09:34.219  INFO 9572 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-11 11:09:34.219  INFO 9572 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1094 ms
2019-06-11 11:09:34.271  WARN 9572 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-06-11 11:09:34.274  INFO 9572 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-06-11 11:09:34.284  INFO 9572 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-11 11:09:34.289 ERROR 9572 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Comment: You should show your app configuration.

Comment: please show your `application.properties` file as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a data start dependency but didn't add the driver for H2 or you want to use another database then you have to add at least: url, username, password

If you don't want to use a database remove the starter from your maven or gradle project file.

Comment: well, first of all i have to know which dependencies i have to add in my SpringBoot Application

Comment: @elbarto, if you are using gradle the dependencies will be in `build.gradle` or if it is maven it will be in `pom.xml`, check for the name `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. May be look into this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html to get more idea

Comment: What type of application do you want to create?

Comment: i want to print an "helloworld" and maybe return some kind of port, so i can go to browser, search "localhost:port" and print "helloworld"

Comment: Then you only need spring-boot-starter-web to have a web container and spring-boot-starter-test for tests. You can remove all other dependencies

Comment: thank you. Now the Application works, exactly as i wanted. The only problem is that if i try to rerun this Application a second time it says that the 8080 port may be already in use. But i think it's normal

Comment: You have to stop the already running application before you lanuch it again.

Answer (score 0):

You might have mentioned below dependency

> `compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'`

So, Spring will look for datasource url in `application.properties`, so remove that or if you you want to work with jdbc add the properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url = <jdbc-url>
spring.datasource.username = <db-username>
spring.datasource.password = <db-password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName = <db-driver>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use any datasource in your application you can put following annotation on your `CiaoMondoApplication` class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If you don't want data access then remove the dependencies to prevent auto configuration.

Answer (score -2):

/*
* Hi Simon,
*
* Couple of questions, have you used the Spring Initializr to build the project or * have you done if from scratch?
*
*  https://start.spring.io/
*
* Is a good place to start:
*
* Here is my basic app (to call a sendgrid api) but that does not matter.
*
*/

```
// Rest Application 

package com.XXXXXXX.restapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApiApplication{

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and that is all that is in my restapi.java

I then have a controller

sendgridcontroller.java

```
import java.io.IOException;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(sendGridController.BASE_URL)
public class sendGridController
{
    public static final String BASE_URL = "/api/v1/feedbacks";

    private final sendGridAPI sendGridAPIService;

    public sendGridController(sendGridAPIImpl sendGridAPIService)
    {
        this.sendGridAPIService = sendGridAPIService;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/sendfeedback")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> sendFeedback(@RequestParam(name="fullname")String fullName,
                                                @RequestParam(name="subject")String subject,
                                                @RequestParam(name="email") String emailAddr,
                                                @RequestParam(name="message")String message )
    {
        Boolean     bReturn = true;

        System.out.println("fullName ="+fullName);
        System.out.println("subject ="+subject);
        System.out.println("email ="+emailAddr);
        System.out.println("message ="+message);

        try
        {
            sendGridAPIService.sendFeedbackEmail(fullName, subject, emailAddr, message);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false,HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bReturn, HttpStatus.OK);

    }


}
```

This is in its own package

Next i created a services package with two files

an Interface sendGridApi.java

```
package com.ea_optimised.restapi.services;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;


public interface sendGridAPI
{
    void sendFeedbackEmail(String fullNameme, String subject, String emailAddr, String message) throws IOException;
}
```

// .... and Finally, I have an implementation of the interface

```
package com.XXXXX.restapi.services;

import com.sendgrid.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.rmi.ServerException;

@Service
public class sendGridAPIImpl implements sendGridAPI
{
    // API_KEY
    private static final String SENDGRID_API_KEY = "My key went here";

    @Override
    public void sendFeedbackEmail(String fullNameme, String subject, String emailAddr, String message) throws IOException
    {

        Email from = new Email(emailAddr);

        Email to = new Email("info@ea-optimised.co.uk");
        //      Email to = new Email("test@example.com");
        Content content = new Content("text/plain", message);
        Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

        SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
        Request request = new Request();
        try
        {
            request.setMethod(Method.POST);
            request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
            request.setBody(mail.build());
            Response response = sg.api(request);
            System.out.println("****\nSTATUS="+response.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("\n***Body :\n\n"+response.getBody());
            System.out.println("***Headers:\n\n"+response.getHeaders());
        }
        catch ( UnknownHostException e )
        {
            System.out.println("***Unknown Host Exception:\n\n");
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println( "SendGrid Failed "+ex.getMessage());
            try
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Finally are you using Gradle or Maven?

Comment: This is a confusing example and not very helpful

Comment: Simon, Why do you think this is confusing as it is a working example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Firstly, start with spring initiaizr to build your scaffolding then go from there